No results return on case when
Trying to update perform one hot encoding to replace values of 1 and 0 based on cell values.
PROC SQL;
   /* Update the 'la_education_graduatea' column */
   UPDATE DMLIB601.LOAN_APPROVAL_SORTED_DS
   SET la_education_graduatea = 
      CASE 
         WHEN UPCASE(TRIM(la_education)) eq 'GRADUATE' THEN 1
         ELSE 0 
      END
   WHERE la_education IS NOT MISSING AND TRIM(la_education) NE '';

   /* Update the 'la_education_notgraduatea' column */
   UPDATE DMLIB601.LOAN_APPROVAL_SORTED_DS
   SET la_education_notgraduatea = 
      CASE  
         WHEN UPCASE(TRIM(la_education)) eq 'NOT GRADUATE' THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
      END
   WHERE la_education IS NOT MISSING AND TRIM(la_education) NE '';
QUIT;

Complied without errors but the results is showing all 0, seems like the update didn't happen.

You don't need any of those trim calls (SAS always trims when comparing strings like that).  Beyond that not seeing anything wrong with the code technically speaking - you may want to look at the incoming data, maybe your data doesn't match what you expect.

Why two separate updates?  Why two different fields, one being the logical inverse of the other?
try
update <mytable>
  set flag1 = <logic-expression>
    , flag2 = NOT <logic-expression>
  ;

Example:
proc sql ;
  create table class as select . as sexF, . as sexM, * from sashelp.class ;
  update class
    set sexF = (sex='F')
      , sexM = (sex='M')
    where sex in ('F','M')
  ;

